# How to grant disabled permissions on a user in mysql

Tags: mysql

For some testing, I had unchecked **INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE** permissions on **Data** in phpMyAdmin.

[image: previleges]

Now when I tried to enable those permissions again, am getting follow error:

[image: permission denied]

Can anyone please guide me how to enable the privileges again?

Comment: See http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/125461/not-able-to-access-user-privileges-for-root-in-mysql

Comment: Thank you @Barmar for sharing the link. It guided me to fix my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this problem in XAMPP on Mac. There are many solutions provided in various posts, but no one was completely fixing my problem. So I am updating the answer, as it may help someone else to fix their problem. Steps followed are:

1. Stop mysql server in XAMPP
   `sudo /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/mysql.server stop`
2. Edit `my.cnf` to skip grant privileges to user
   `sudo vi /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/my.cnf`
3. Add `skip-grant-tables` at the end of `[mysqld]` section
4. Restart mysql server
   `sudo /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/mysql.server restart`
5. Connect with mysql server (username and password are not required)
   `mysql`
6. Type following commands respectively:

   `UPDATE mysql.user SET Grant_priv='Y', Super_priv='Y' WHERE User='root';`

   `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`

   `GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost';`

Now you are good to go :)

Comment: Isn't this explained in the dba.SE question? This question should be closed because it's off-topic for SO, it shouldn't be given an answer.

Comment: The link above gives the broader idea. But that didn't work for me